# Vaadin23 vaadin.eagerServerLoad=true and BeforeEnterObserver

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I switched to `vaadin.eagerServerLoad=true` in order to fix the issue with incorrect HTTP status code (I need to return 404 when it is needed).

I also noticed one issue which potentially maybe related to the `vaadin.eagerServerLoad=true`. On the views with `com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterObserver` the method `BeforeEnterObserver.beforeEnter` is executed twice when I for the very first time enter the page (please note that there is no such issue when I navigate between views in the already constructed UI). This is why now as a temporal fix I have to call `removeAll()` as a first line in the `beforeEnter` method.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked if it calls beforeEnter on the same instance or are there maybe two instances?

Comment: The method on the same instance is called 2 times

Comment: related issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16046